# How do I make more money?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've played through GTA V offline a couple times, but I can't seem to get enough money to buy the Los Santos Golf Club, which is $150,000,000 according to the [GTA V Wikia](http://gta.wikia.com/Properties_in_GTA_V).

The question I want to ask is; does anybody know how I can get more money?
I've swam past the crashed plane and gotten the briefcase (see below), but collecting that briefcase is around $25,000, if I remember correctly. I feel like the briefcase is more for a little spending money, something you can carry around and not have to worry about losing, if you get killed.

[Location](http://gta.wikia.com/File:Michael%27s_briefcase_location.jpg)

I want to make as much money as possible, and buying the second most expensive property, The Tivoli Cinema, which costs $30,000,000, is the most efficient, I think. That will still take me a lot of time, though.

Anybody know a way which I can get $150,000,000 in less than 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

If you play through the game you will get assassination missions from lester. Save these till the end of the game and when you play through them listen to the stock lester tells you to buy, put all of your money in this stock and complete the mission. Go home and sleep and when you wake up sell the stock. Repeat this for all of the assassination mission.